# ddl Selected Value invalid error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list inside of a DataList EditItemTemplate, fueled by a SQLDataSource (below).  The parameter @panelid is being set in codebehind on the SQL databinding event, and that seems to be working fine.  Contents are accurate and what I expected.

Then I tried setting the selected value using `Bind("scopeid")`, which should be fine.  `scopeid` and `equipmentid` are related, in fact `scopeid` is populated by `equipmentid` in the footer of this same datalist, so their values should be matching (and they are).  This should push the `scopeid` of the chosen record to the selected item in the ddl.  However, I get the `'ddlEquipment' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.  Parameter name: value` error when switching to my EditItemTemplate.  Any ideas?

```
<asp:DropDownList class="smallInputddl" ID="ddlEquipment" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlEditEquipment" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("scopeid")%>' DataTextField="modelnumber" DataValueField="equipmentid" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlEditEquipment" runat="server" OnDataBinding="sqlEditEquipment_DataBinding" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductionDatabaseConnectionString1 %>"
    SelectCommand="select * from tblsls_equipmentscope where proposalnumber in (select proposalnumber from tblsls_cntrlpanel where id = @panelid)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="panelid" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

To demonstrate, here's a Sql query to show the relationship between `scopeid` and `equipmentid`.  tblsls_cntrlvfd also has the id from tblsls_cntrlpanel.:

```
select e.equipmentid, c.scopeid from tblsls_equipmentscope e
left join tblsls_cntrlvfd c on e.equipmentid = c.scopeid
where proposalnumber in (select proposalnumber from tblsls_cntrlpanel where id = 20)
```

Results:

```
equipmentid scopeid
----------- --------
9513        9513
9541        9541
9543        NULL

(3 row(s) affected)
```

The gist is that the equipment exists off in it's own little world, and controls in it's.  Both get tied to a proposal.  There's also a VFD that is associated to both a control panel and a specific piece of equipment.

Comment: As it shows in result set, scope id is also having null value. I guess you need to check this.

Comment: scopeid has null because it doesn't have a record for that equipmentid, and it shouldn't.  It's not trying to push null into the datalist, it's trying to push either 9541 or 9513, depending on which record I'm editing.  Clarifying in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I'm in the habit of keeping SQL data sources that just fuel a drop down list right with the list they populate.  Usually this is desired.  In this situation, keeping it with the list resulted in me having to use a work around to set it's parameter's value.  It could not see the label it needed to from where it was, so I was setting the default value in the data sources `Databinding` event.  This works fine on it's own, and the list populates as expected.  As soon as you try to set the `SelectedValue` however, when the datasource is having it's parameters setup in `databinding`, what happens is a slight loading out of order issue.  These eventually wind up running at the same time, so the datasource hasn't run and populated it's dataset yet, `SelectedValue` sees a set with 0 entries in it.

Moving the `SQLDataSource` out so that it could see the control I originally wanted it to solved the issue.  It no longer needed to have it's parameter set through code, it's list is essentially static.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include a 'blank' option in your DDL for it to match the null value to. It's trying to find a match in the list to the cell's original value(null) but since that isn't an available option it's throwing the exception. Just set index 0 of your DDL to be blank.